# Docker kafka on MacOS M1 Issues stuck on configuring

Tags: macos, docker, apache-kafka, apple-m1

I use macOS M1 Big Sur 11.2.3, but my kafka cannot running well and cannot create/list the topics. I don't know its because the OS or not, but the log for kafka is only like this:

[docker-compose logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6icAa.jpg)

[list the topics logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEabD.png)

here's my docker compose:

```
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    hostname: zookeeper
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
    environment:
      ZOO_MY_ID: 1
    networks:
      - kafka_net
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    container_name: kafka
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    expose:
      - 29092
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: localhost
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT: 9092
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INSIDE://0.0.0.0:29092,OUTSIDE://0.0.0.0:9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INSIDE://kafka:29092,OUTSIDE://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INSIDE
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
    restart: always
    networks:
      - kafka_net
networks:
  kafka_net:
    driver: bridge
```

I think kafka not yet to running, So i cannot list/create a topics. Do you guys have any idea of this? i already search possibilities about this, but i still don't have the problem solving. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

For startup kafka in docker on mac m1 i do next things :

1. Clone kafka repo and build on my macbook pro m1 (**./gradlew clean releaseTarGz**)
2. Create docker-compose project dir with next structure

- root dir

  - kafka_m1

    - kafka (unziped kafka distr)

    - Dockerfile

  - docker-compose.yml

3. Configure **server.properties** file (**root dir/kafka_m1/kafka/config/server.properties**). Main params:

```
   zookeeper.connect=zookeeper:2181
   listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092
   advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092
   listener.security.protocol.map=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT
```

4. kafka`s **Dockerfile** (**openjdk:15.0.2-jdk** was build for m1):

```
    FROM openjdk:15.0.2-jdk
    
    WORKDIR /
    COPY . /
    
    EXPOSE 9092
    EXPOSE 8092
    EXPOSE 9092
    EXPOSE 10092
    EXPOSE 11092
    EXPOSE 12092
    
    ENTRYPOINT [ "/kafka/bin/kafka-server-start.sh", "/kafka/config/server.properties" ]
```

5. **docker-compose.yml** (i choose **zookeeper:3.7.0** because it has arm build):

```
  version: "2"
  services:
  zookeeper:
    image: zookeeper:3.7.0
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
  kafka:
    build: ./kafka_m1
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:9092:9092"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

6. Start docker-compose with kafka_m1 image building.

It`s fast receipt for run local kafka in docker

Comment: Does anyone tried this as I have the same situation now?

Answer (score 4):

Just add platform to your docker-compose.yml file:

> platform: linux/amd64

```
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    platform: linux/amd64
    container_name: zookeeper
    hostname: zookeeper
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
    environment:
      ZOO_MY_ID: 1
    networks:
      - kafka_net
    ...
```

If above option doesn't help then you should try the following:

```
version: '3'

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
  
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    container_name: kafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: localhost
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks! wurstmeister images are working fine on my Apple M1

Answer (score 1):

the `docker-compose.yaml` file is ok, you just have to execute the following commands into the kafka container:

1. kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper zookeeper:2181 --topic test --create --partitions 3 --replication-factor 1
2. kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper zookeeper:2181 --list

btw: you can enter to the kafka container using the command: docker exec -it CONTAINER_ID bash

Answer (score 1):

Let me provide the docker-compose file that I spent a whole day creating.

Below docker-compose file builds containers for the zookeeper, Kafka, and kafka-manager [CMAK](https://github.com/yahoo/CMAK)

```
version: '3'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    container_name: kafka
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "1099:1099"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka
      JMX_PORT: 1099
  kafka_manager:
    image: hlebalbau/kafka-manager:stable
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    environment:
      ZK_HOSTS: zookeeper:2181
    command: -Dpidfile.path=/dev/null
```

`docker-compose up --build -d`

Then for managing cluster through CMAK you require to execute following

```
docker exec -it zookeeper bash
./bin/zkCli.sh
create /kafka-manager/mutex ""
create /kafka-manager/mutex/locks ""
create /kafka-manager/mutex/leases ""
```

Comment: I am getting error:
error getting credentials - err: docker-credential-desktop resolves to executable in current directory (./docker-credential-desktop), out: ``
I am using Colima, instead of Docker Desktop

Answer (score 0):

This mentioned `docker-compose.yml` is working for me on `Mac M1-Pro`. The latest Kafka also doesn't need `zookeeper`. This also contains `Kafka-UI` container.

```
version: '3'

networks:
  app-tier:
    driver: bridge

services:
  kafka:
    image: 'bitnami/kafka:latest'
    container_name: kafka
    hostname: kafka
    ports:
      - '9092:9092'
    networks:
      - app-tier
    environment:
      KAFKA_CFG_NODE_ID: 0
      KAFKA_CFG_PROCESS_ROLES: controller,broker
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS: 0@kafka:29093
      KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES: CONTROLLER
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: 'PLAINTEXT://kafka:29092,CONTROLLER://kafka:29093,PLAINTEXT_HOST://0.0.0.0:9092'
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092

  kafka-ui:
    image: provectuslabs/kafka-ui:latest
    container_name: kafka-ui
    ports:
      - "8090:8080"
    depends_on:
      - kafka
    networks:
      - app-tier
    environment:
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_NAME: local
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka:29092
```

Screenshot of `Kafka-UI`

[image]

Link: https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/kafka